# Paste Special error 1004 PasteSpecial method of Range class failed VBA. Can i handle it using error handling?

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked over the solutions for this Run time error over whole internet, but was not able to find something useful for my code.

can i use Try & Catch here for re-running that specific part of code, Because every time i run my  code stops on the below mentioned line and i press F8 code starts running back.

Paste special error occurs whenever i try to run code for bulk files.
Please refer error lines below with **
Look on the code below:

```
If lRnewapp >1 Then
                wksoldApp. Unprotect "iti3.0" wksoldApp.Range("A2:D"&Roldapp).ClearContents
                Application. Wait (Now () + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 
                
                WksNewApp.Range("B2:C" & 1Rnewapp).Copy
                Application. Wait (Now () + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
                 
                **wksoldApp.Range("A2"). Paste Special (xl PasteValue)**
                Application. Wait (Now) + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 
                
                **wksNewApp.Range("D2:D" & 1Rnewapp).Copy**
                Application. Wait (Now I) + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 
                
                **WksoldApp.Range("D2"). Paste Special (x1 Pastevalue)**
                Application. Wait (Now () + TimeValue("00:00:02"} 
                
                wksNewApp.Range("E2:E" & 1Rnewapp). Copy
                Application. Wait (Now) + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 
                
                wksOldApp.Range("C2"). Paste Special (xl PasteValues)
                Application. Wait (Now) + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 
                
                wksoldApp.Range("A2:D2").Copy
                Application. Wait (Now) + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 
                
                wksoldApp.Range("A3:D" 1Rnewapp). Paste Special xl Paste formats
                Application. Wait (Now) + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 
                
                wksoldApp. Protect it13.0", AllowFormattingcolumna:-True, AllowFormattingRows: True, userinterfaceonly: True, AllowFiltering: True 
            
            wkoldApp.Range("E2") - int (A2) 
            wksoldApp.Range("E2:E" & 1 Rnewapp) .Fill Down
                Application. Wait (Now) + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 
                
                wksOldApp.Range("E2:E" & 1Rnewapp).Copy
                Application. Wait (Now () + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 
                
     wksoldApp.Range("A2"). Paste Special (xlPasteValues) 
    
    wksoldApp.Columns (2). Number Format - "O" 

wksoldApp.Range("E:E").clearContents
   
 wksoldApp.Range("A2"). BorderAround xlThin 
   
 wksoldApp.Range("A2").Copy 
   
 wksoldApp.Range("A2:D" & 1newapp). PasteSpecial xl Paste Format 

WksoldApp.Range("AZ:D" IRnewapp). Font.Size - "S"
```

End If

Comment: Yes you can use regular VBA error handling: see here for a good overview  - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm#:~:text=On%20Error%20Goto%20%3A,to%20terminate%20the%20VBA%20program.   Please do not post code as a picture - you can copy/paste the relevant section to your post as text.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for sharing the material, It'll definitely help me out.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TimWilliams can you please take a look. ?